# How to make sure that certain code is not run more than 1 every 1 seconds?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a program that download tons of files from the net

I have several threads downloading data.

After each data is called, I need to update the managed object contexts

If 10 threads finish loading at about the same time, then the managed object context will get run 10 times.

The truth is I only need to run it once.

What I want to do is to create a method that accept a block.

What should I do to make a function that receive a block, but if that block has been run less than 1 second ago, it won't run the block but instead would postpone the second running till 1 seconds no matter how often the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike Ash has already implemented a [timer class](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-02-background-timers.html) for this.

You need to init it with a behaviour type, depending on the exact behaviour you want:

- `MABGTimerDelay` means every time you call `afterDelay:1.0 do:^{ /*code*/ }` it will set the fire date back so that it only gets run a full second after the **last** call.
- `MABGTimerCoalesce` means every time you call `afterDelay:1.0 do:^{ /*code*/ }` it will set the fire date back so that it only gets run a full second after the **first** call.

If it's already been run, both behaviours will allow you to run it again, but only after the delay has passed again.

Answer (score 1):

If the block that gets run is always the same, you could have a loop running on a one second interval that checks a boolean value and only executes the block if the boolean value is YES. Something like this:

```
    BOOL needsUpdate;
    -(void) loop {
    if (needsUpdate) {
        //Run Block
        needsUpdate = NO;
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(loop) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
```

When the threads finish loading, you just set `needsUpdate = YES` and the loop takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread finished call the method in the main thread. In that method make a timer with 1 second delay.

```
- (void)threadDidFinish
{
    if (_saveTimer != nil)
    {
        _saveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(saveTimerDidFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)saveTimerDidFire
{
    [_saveTimer invalidate];
    _saveTimer = nil;

    // save the changes
}
```

This code will ensure you will save every second regardless of the number of times threadDidFinish was called. NSTimer* _saveTimer is an instance variable.